# Marking the items in an "enumerate" list

Tags: numbering, lists, enumitem

I am using LaTeX and `enumitem`.

In a list of the kind of

```
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,label=(\arabic*)]... \end{enumerate}
```

instead of having items numbered (1), (2), (3), ...,
or another of the classical numeration,
can I have items numbered with MY choice of marks,
e.g., (sc), (cg), (cp) ?

[This particular sequence would be for 
"sigma-compact", "compactly generated", "compactly presented".]

Comment: You can add explicit labels to any list item: `\item[(sc)] ...`. Do the sc, cg, etc. labels correspond to numbers in any regular way?  If so you could make a command to map numbers into them, but otherwise I don't see a way to do this automatically.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the description environment maybe.

Answer (score 4):

As Alan Munn points out, in this case you likely want to do just

```
\item[(sc)]
```

If you insisted on having it automated, you can do the following little trick:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*\mylabseq[1]{\ifcase#1\or sc\or cg\or cp\else#1\fi}

\begin{document} 

\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,label=(\noexpand\mylabseq{\arabic*})]
\item foo
\item bar
\item baz
\item buzz
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```